Tikz fill opposite side for a fundamental domain
I'm trying to reproduce fundamental domain diagrams in this paper. Especially, I'm trying to draw the following fundamental domain of $\Gamma_1(6)$

and I was able to draw the line and half circles based on this answer without shading:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \draw[very thick]
        (-.5,1) -- (-.5,0)
        (-1/2, 0) arc (180:0:1/12)
        (-1/3, 0) arc (180:0:1/6)
        (0, 0) arc (180:0:1/6)
        (1/3, 0) arc (180:0:1/12)
        (.5, 0) -- (.5,1);
    \draw(-0.7,0) -- (0.7,0);
    \draw(0,-.2) -- (0,1);
    \draw(-.5,.02)--(-.5,-.02)node[below]{$-\frac{1}{2}$};
    \draw(.5,.02)--(.5,-.02)node[below]{$\frac{1}{2}$};
    \draw(-1/3,.02)--(-1/3,-.02)node[below]{$-\frac{1}{3}$};
    \draw(1/3,.02)--(1/3,-.02)node[below]{$\frac{1}{3}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}


Now, once I add fill option, I get the following opposite shading:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \draw[very thick, fill=gray!30]
        (-.5,1) -- (-.5,0)
        (-1/2, 0) arc (180:0:1/12)
        (-1/3, 0) arc (180:0:1/6)
        (0, 0) arc (180:0:1/6)
        (1/3, 0) arc (180:0:1/12)
        (.5, 0) -- (.5,1);
    \draw(-0.7,0) -- (0.7,0);
    \draw(0,-.2) -- (0,1);
    \draw(-.5,.02)--(-.5,-.02)node[below]{$-\frac{1}{2}$};
    \draw(.5,.02)--(.5,-.02)node[below]{$\frac{1}{2}$};
    \draw(-1/3,.02)--(-1/3,-.02)node[below]{$-\frac{1}{3}$};
    \draw(1/3,.02)--(1/3,-.02)node[below]{$\frac{1}{3}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}


Of course, this is not what I want. I also tried to reverse the order of drawing vertical lines and arcs but it didn't work. Is there an easy way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

You have to connect the paths, notize the use of -- connectors in the following code:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=gray]
        (-.5,1) -- (-.5,0) --
        (-1/2, 0) arc (180:0:1/12) --
        (-1/3, 0) arc (180:0:1/6) --
        (0, 0) arc (180:0:1/6) --
        (1/3, 0) arc (180:0:1/12) --
        (.5, 0) -- (.5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thanks! works perfectly.
